# ActiveWorkbook.Saved versus ThisWorkbook.Saved versus Me.Saved

Tags: excel, vba, performance

I write Excel VBA reports that tap into SQL databases.  I'm also in a company that uses dozens of such reports, and any user could have multiple such reports open at once from multiple different sources.  Because of this, it is paramount that code does not affect or interfere with any other open workbooks.

My current report unavoidably uses volatile functions, so users that open and then immediately close the file will get prompted with a Save? dialog.  Searching online has always pointed to using

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    ActiveWorkbook.Saved = True
End Sub
```

While effective, I've never been a big fan because of the non-specific nature of "ActiveWorkbook".

**Question:**

What are the pros/cons/pitfalls of using any of the following options-

1. ActiveWorkbook.Saved
2. ThisWorkbook.Saved
3. Me.Saved
4. Something_I_haven't_thought_of.Saved

Comment: Wasn't sure about "Performance" tag.  Please remove if inappropriate.

Comment: For anybody stumbling across this in search of an answer to "why does Excel want me to save?": This is an Event.  It should be saved in the ThisWorkbook code section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`ActiveWorkbook`**

I would argue that there *are no pros* to using `ActiveWorkbook`, as a direct reference to what you're working with should **always** be preferable, especially in the case stated above where multiple workbooks are involved. Even in the event of opening and working with arbitrary workbooks whose names you don't specifically know (via a `FSO` or `Dir()` loop), you can always set a workbook variable equal to the return value of a `Workbook.Open` function.

**`ThisWorkbook`**

Any time you have code working with more than one workbook or even code working with one workbook while multiple workbooks are open, I would recommend `ThisWorkbook`. It is versatile in that it can be used in object code modules and generic modules to return a consistent reference to the workbook it is placed within. There really aren't any cons to explicitly specifying `ThisWorkbook` when that's what you mean to reference.

**`Me`**

`Me` and `ThisWorkbook` are interchangeable when using them inside the `ThisWorkbook` object code module, but outside of that, `Me` refers to the object which it is placed within. For instance `Me.Name` inside a worksheet object code module will get you the name of the worksheet. Doing the same inside the workbook code module will get you the name of the workbook.

For the sake of clarity and re-usability, I would personally recommend `ThisWorkbook` out of all 3.

Comment: -Thanks for confirming my suspicions.  Now to just get all of those other search results to agree...

Answer (score -1):

**Active workbook** is the workbook that is in use/activated (hence can change during code execution) and thus less reliable.

**This workbook** is the workbook on which the code is run. Hence, a good option if that is the workbook you want to refer to.

**"Me"** refers to where the code is. E.g. if in sheetmodule, it refers to that sheet, if in a userform module it refers to that module, if in thisworkbook module it is the same as 'thisworkbook', etc.

Defining a **variable** as workbook can refer to any open workbook. Can be redefined as desired in the code and hence very flexible as long as you know the name of the book

Application.DisplayAlerts = False can be used to suppress save/overwrite requests. Which can be very handy if you do not want users to receive a prompt.
 Do re-enable as this is a powerful yet 'dangerous' piece of code.

Comment: @Starshine, apparently you do not like any of the answers. Perhaps you should clarify your question to get a more appropriate answer. What is the issue and the desired solution?

Comment: I was not the down-voter, but I tend to agree with it. I don't believe "Me" can refer to anything other than the object it is being used within.

Comment: Thanks for the response Starshine. I did not realise that "me" was a special name, I thought you used it as a variable. Updated the text accordingly